# Is it possible to call the winapi multimedia timer from a Unity3D program without crashing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, winapi

Question also asked [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1637786/invoking-windows-multimedia-timer-results-to-hang.html).

I am on Windows 10, Unity Editor 2018.3.12f1

I have a requirement for very fast (500 Hz) and precise updates, "independent" from the Unity main thread. I am targeting windows desktop only, so the [Multimedia Timers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/multimedia/multimedia-timers) seemed as a good (the only?) fit. However I witness some weird crashes.

I tried [this](https://github.com/mzboray/HighPrecisionTimer) library which also includes a working example, and I also created this very simple mono behaviour to test it but with same results:

```
 using System.Threading;
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 using System;

 public class MultimediaTimer : MonoBehaviour
 {
     private UInt32 userCtx = 0;

     void Start()
     {
         Run();
         //Thread r = new Thread(() => Run()); -- Ignore this
         //r.Start();
     }

     void Run()
     {
         MultimediaTimerCallback Callback = new MultimediaTimerCallback(TimerCallbackMethod);
         uint timerId = TimeSetEvent(100, 5, Callback, ref userCtx, 1);
         Thread.Sleep(1000);
         TimeKillEvent(timerId);
     }

     private static void TimerCallbackMethod(uint id, uint msg, ref uint userCtx, uint rsv1, uint rsv2)
     {
         Debug.Log("Hi");
     }

     private delegate void MultimediaTimerCallback(UInt32 id, UInt32 msg, ref UInt32 userCtx, UInt32 rsv1, UInt32 rsv2);

     [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "timeSetEvent")]
     private static extern UInt32 TimeSetEvent(UInt32 msDelay, UInt32 msResolution, MultimediaTimerCallback callback, ref UInt32 userCtx, UInt32 eventType);

     [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "timeKillEvent")]
     private static extern UInt32 TimeKillEvent(UInt32 uTimerId);
 }
```

When in Editor, when I press the play button, my sample game seems to be working correctly (ie prints in the Debug console, and with great precision when I used stopwatch to measure), but when i stop the game and try to run it again, the Editor hangs.

When i build and play, again everything seems normal (no debug messages there of course), but when i attempt to close the program via the 'X' button it hangs again.

My question is very simple. Is it possible to reliably call the multimedia timer from a Unity program? And if not could someone explain this behaviour I observe? I could encapsulate my timer logic in a separate process and use some form of IPC to achieve my requirement, but I would prefer for convenience to stay withing Unity. (Of course if you know any alternatives, by all means do say them)

Comment: did you try to store `Thread r` rather in a global value and kill it alongside with Unity like `private void OnDestroy(){ if(r!=null) r.Abort(); }` maybe the issue is that it's still running somewhere? And the same maybe also for `TimeKillEvent(timerId);`

Comment: Yes, doesn't change the behaviour. I also tried to run the code from the main thread (multimedia timer is using it's own thread for the callback eitherway) but still the same. Utilizing `OnDestroy` doesn't help whatsoever unfortunately. By the way I don't need a Thread, for now I just need to invoke the timer and not crash, thread or not.

Comment: Also, this happens for both periodic or one time events (1 or 0 as the last argument of `TimeSetEvent` respectively)

Comment: Having messed with threads in Unity before, if you don't shut them down when you leave play mode (`OnDestroy` is not sufficient, you need to use [`OnApplicationQuit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationQuit.html)) then you get the behavior you describe.

Comment: Removed the misleading threading part. Even calling it on the main thread produces the same outcome so I believe it is irrelevant.